# Python Truncating to 32-bit

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

How do I truncate my return value to 32-bits? I have the following code:

```
def rotate_left(value, shift):
    return hex((value << shift) | (value >> (32 - shift)))
```

I would like the return value to be

`0x0000_000A` instead of `0xA_0000_000A` when calling `rotate_right(0xA00_0000)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`0xFFFFFFFF` is 32 bits so you can just do a logical or:

```
result = number & 0xFFFFFFFF
if result & (1 << 31):  # negative value
    result -= 1 << 32
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd prefer to do this generally and not just for 32 bits:

```
def truncate(value, bit_count):
    return value & (2**bit_count - 1)
```

This works because `2**bit_count -1` is all 1's in binary.